# create variable of select option name instead of value in php

Tags: php

I have a select field and i am using my option value as a variable for some further work but i would like to create a second variable for the name of my option to use elsewhere. 
This is my form

```
<form action="second.php" method="post" class="form">
        Client:<select class="default" id="client" name="client" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select Client</option>
        <option value="clienta" name"Client A">Client A</option>
        <option value="clientb" name "Client B">Client B</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In my second.php file i am getting the value for client like this:

```
$client = $_POST["client"];
```

Im not sure how to get the name for client instead of value.
i have tried:

```
$client_name = $_POST["client.name"];
$client_name = $_POST["client[name]"];
$client_name = $_POST["client(name)"];
```

But none of these work, they all come back blank when i want to return the name of the option e.g.
`"Client A"`  instead of `"clienta"`

Does anyone know how i could get to the name field instead of the value from my select?

Comment: You can't use the name in option, you get only value so based on the value you need to make an array in the other side and get a correct name you want.

Comment: So cant be done with a single select?

Comment: _“Does anyone know how i could get to the name field instead of the value from my select?”_ - by looking the name up _using_ the value …? You obviously _have_ both name and value available on the server side (otherwise you could not _create_ this select field in the first place) - so stick the names into an array, use the value as key … something like that. The other option would be to combine name and value into a single string, that could be used as the value attribute content then, and you’ll have to take both apart on the server side again.

Comment: I as know in single select it not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Need Both value and Name. the best way to archive is by combining them in value

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['client']))
{
$pair = explode("/", $_POST["client"]);

$name   = $pair[0];
$value = $pair[1];

print "Key: $name<br />";
print "Value: $value<br />";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="" name="form">
<select name="client">
    <option value="clienta/Client A">Client A</option>
    <option value="clientb/Client B">Client B</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: unfortunately i need both the value and the name for different things. Might not be possible with a single select.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need add attribute `name` `<option>` element:

```
<form action="second.php" method="post" class="form">
        Client:<select multiple="multiple" class="default" id="client" name="client[]" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select Client</option>
        <option value="ClientA">Client A</option>
        <option value="ClientB">Client B</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In php:

```
$clients = $_POST['client']; // will be array with selected options
```

Comment: Ive already got that bit, i was hoping to get two variables, the value and also the name, seems like it might not be possible with a single select.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like Below Code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form class="form-horizontal" action="#">
           <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="client">Client:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select class="form-control" id="client" name="client" required>
                      <option value="" selected>Select Client</option>
                      <option value="clienta" name="Client A">Client A</option>
                      <option value="clientb" name="Client B">Client B</option>
                   </select>
               </div>
           </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                 <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" value="Submit">
              </div>
         </div>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>

<script>
   $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(){
     var option_value = $('#client').val();
     var option_name = $('#client').find('option:selected').attr('name');
     $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"second.php",
       data:"option_value="+option_value+"&option_name="+option_name,
       success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
    echo $option_value = $_POST['option_value'];
    echo $option_name = $_POST['option_name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="second.php" method="post" class="form">
    Client:<select class="default" id="client" data-name="client" required>
    <option value="" selected>Select Client</option>
    <option value="clienta" data-name="Client A">Client A</option>
    <option value="clientb" data-name="Client B">Client B</option>
    <input type="button" id ="button" value="send">
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#button').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'second.php',
        data: {'clinet_val':$('#client').val(),'clinet_name':$('#client').find(':selected').data('name')},
        success:function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }

    });
});
```

});